# Java counting string occurrences in ArrayList

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have written a program where I have N strings and Q queries that are also strings. The goal is to determine **how many times each query appears in the N strings.**

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SparseArrays{


// count the number of occurances of a string in an array
int countStringOccurance(ArrayList<String> arr, String str){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++) {
        if (str==arr.get(i)) {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    return count;
}


void start(){
    // scanner object
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // ask for user to input num strings
    System.out.println("How many string would you like to enter?");
    // store the number of strings
    int numStrings = input.nextInt();
    // to get rid of extra space
    input.nextLine();

    // ask user to enter strings
    System.out.println("Enter the "+numStrings+" strings.");
    ArrayList<String> stringInputArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=0; i<numStrings; i++) {
        stringInputArray.add(input.nextLine());
    } // all strings are in the stringInputArray

    // ask user to input num queries
    System.out.println("Enter number of queries.");
    int numQueries = input.nextInt();
    // to get rid of extra space
    input.nextLine();

    // ask user to enter string queries
    System.out.println("Enter the "+numQueries+" queries.");
    ArrayList<String> stringQueriesArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=0; i<numQueries; i++) {
        stringQueriesArray.add(input.nextLine());
    } // all string queries are in the stringQueriesArray

    for (int i=0; i<stringQueriesArray.size(); i++) {
        int result = 
      countStringOccurance(stringInputArray,stringQueriesArray.get(i));
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}

void printArr(ArrayList<String> arr){
    for (int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(arr.get(i));
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparseArrays obj = new SparseArrays();
    obj.start();
}
}
```

When I run my code and enter 4 strings such as {abc,abc,abc,def} and 3 queries such as {abc,def,ghi} I expect to get 3, 1 and 0 for my output since there are 3 "abc", 1 "def" and 0 "ghi". However, the output is zero for all the queries.

I am pretty sure the problem is from the method 
**int countStringOccurance(ArrayList arr, String str)** which is supposed to give me the number of times a string is repeated in an ArrayList of Strings.

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: _don't_ compare strings like this --> `if (str==arr.get(i))` , should be --> `if (str.equals(arr.get(i)))`

Comment: @Aominé Thanks! That solved the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `String.equals()` to compare strings, not `==`.  Instead of:

```
if (str1==str2)   //  WRONG!!!
```

write

```
if (str1.equals(str2))  // Correct
```

Comment: There is also `.equalsIgnoreCase()` if the comparison does not need to be case-sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

```
// count the number of occurances of a string in an array
int countStringOccurance(ArrayList<String> arr, String str){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++) {
        if (str.equals(arr.get(i))) { //<-- change your condition to this
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Read more on 
[What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.equals()` between two objects, not `==`. And then, when you have an error, try to put some log trace in the sensitive part, with simple `System.out.println()` for example, in order to check if each object and variables are well filled. Can help you to solve this kind of problem !

Answer (score 0):

There's already a builtin method that handles this, `Collections#frequency`:

```
int occurrences = Collections.frequency(list, "String here");
```